# using Spree as a framework rather than a plattform in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

As I understand Spree is a shopping platform to build your shop.

I would like to use Spree partially and as a framework for some e-commerce features. The rest of my application has nothing to do with e-commerce and it is already running with it's own user authentication, but since spree is using devise too, it might be possible to merge it into my project.

Has anybody used spree as a framework for a own rails project?
If yes would you like to share your experiences (maybe you can list key benefits and disadvantages).

Answer (score 4):

Spree and ror-e have a few differences, some of them described [here](http://ror-e.com/posts/1). But note that the writer of that post is biased (he admits that he is) and that some of the comments are from a biased perspective.

That being said, I think Spree and ror-e are solving different problems / answering different questions. Spree now has early stage venture capital funding and is building relationships with 3rd party services like analytics and payment gateways - with the goal in mind to be the one stop shop for all ecommerce needs. Ror-e is built with a perspective of being a solid base from which to build out a customizeable application. Spree also has [deface](https://github.com/railsdog/deface), which is a tool aimed at allowing designer-friendly interactions with updating the UI.

Spree recently released some updates that are namespaced and make it suitable for a mountable app, and ror-e also offers that functionality. Both would probably be suitable to build with custom Rails functonality. In both cases, you have to accept/be happy the assumptions that the software makes and see if those assumptions suit your business model.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in the middle of a project and I am using Spree more as a framework than as a platform. Our client do not sell directly online but still, it is a great start and is easily extendable to fit your needs.

It sticks with the "Rails way", is up to date, stable and have a great community. It takes some time to get started to understand how everything's work, but once you're at full speed, you'll see the clear benefits. There is also a bunch of plugins. Hang on Github as they might not be that easy to find for the 1.0 versions.

I should also mention that it could be mounted in an already existing Rails 3.1.X app as it is now a mountable engine with isolated namespace.

If you start today, you should start with [1.0.0.rc2](http://rubygems.org/gems/spree) and use [edge guides](http://edgeguides.spreecommerce.com). There is almost always some people to help you on IRC (Freenode: #spree) or the mailing list (on Google Groups).

Comment: thanks for sharing. ror-ecommerce seems to be leaner http://ror-e.com/posts/1-ror-ecommerce-vs-spree - I would like to hear your opinion about it.

Comment: The community is clearly smaller. You can see it quickly by the watchers on github. Well, this might not that scientific, but gives an idea...also, it is not a mountable engine with separated namespace. You could have namespacing collisions and problems. That said, I haven't used it. Seems to be less doc and smaller community.

Comment: After reading the ror-e link you gave, it looks the writer haven't worked with 1.0 as a lot changed. That said, there is (at least) some points he's right: i18n, the "Cart" feature and probably more, I don't know 100% of Spree!

Comment: See Josh's answer in the comments too. Spree Commerce had 1.5M$ in funding a few months ago (october I think) and a few guys working full time on it!

Comment: I liked your Answer (thank you), but it doesn't tell disadvantages and since you are in progress I can not expect a more accurate answer.

Comment: Hey...  I created ror-e.  If you have any specific Questions feel free to ask me on github.  I'd love to answer any specific questions anyone has.  I'm drhenner on github.